# Calling a function after a function

Tags: jquery, text

I'm creating a website and using jQuery functions. I can't seem to get past the following problem.

I've got three buttons, ones is clicked ten new buttons appear. Depending on which of the initial three buttons is clicked, the next 10 buttons should make a specific text appear. The problem is when I try to call the text, all the texts appear even though I just called `p#icpast` for example.

Three initial buttons

```
function past() {
    $(this).addClass("emphasis");
    $("p#present").removeClass("emphasis");
    $("p#future").removeClass("emphasis");
    $("div#text2").slideDown(200);
    $(".competency").hide();

    $(".1").fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".2").fadeTo(1000, 0);
    $(".3").fadeTo(1000, 0);
    k = 1;
    return false

    $("div#container1").click(ic(displaytext));    
}    
function present() {
    $(this).addClass("emphasis");
    $("p#past").removeClass("emphasis");
    $("p#future").removeClass("emphasis");
    $("div#text2").slideDown(200);
    $(".competency").hide();

    $(".1").fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".2").fadeTo(1000, 0.7);
    $(".3").fadeTo(1000, 0);
    k = 2;
    return false
}    
function future() {
    $(this).addClass("emphasis");
    $("p#past").removeClass("emphasis");
    $("p#present").removeClass("emphasis");
    $("div#text2").slideDown(300);
    $(".competency").hide();

    $(".1").fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".2").fadeTo(1000, 0.7);
    $(".3").fadeTo(1000, 0.6);
    k = 3;
    return false
}

$("p#past").click(past)
$("p#present").click(present);
$("p#future").click(future);
```

one of the 10 buttons

```
function ic() {
    $("div#text2").slideUp(200)
    $("p").removeClass("emphasis");
    $("#icpast").slideDown(300).siblings().hide()
    return false
}
```

`p#icpast` is the text I want to make appear

Some text I want to make appear:

```
<div>
    <p class="competency" id="icpast">Icpast</p>
    <p class="competency" id="icpresent">Icpresent</p>
    <p class="competency" id="icfuture">Icfuture</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your html also?

Comment: I've added the html I need to call

Comment: Is that html repeated in the page more times?

Comment: no, it's just three example texts that should appear. Everytime I try to use p#icpast to make the text appear, also #icpresent and #icfuture appear.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with this? I want to help, but not clear how your html/script/CSS is. Please complete this and post back: http://jsfiddle.net/wB3yy/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wB3yy/10/

If you push past you can see the new 10 buttons appear, if you push IC the right text should appear. At this point it doesn't matter wether or not you've selected past, present or future, the same text keeps appearing.

Comment: You code need a lot of optimisation, it would make it much easier for you... can you describe what should happen and I try to make a optimised version. Ignore the code that you have, explain the behaviour you want

Answer (score 0):

Your code could use a lot of optimization. Here is a suggestion:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var k = 0;

    $(".2").fadeTo(0, 0);
    $(".3").fadeTo(0, 0);
    $(".1").fadeTo(0, 0);
    $(".competency").hide(0);

    // alleen groot blijven als hij geklikt is > nog aanpassen

    /* MOVED TO CSS
        $(".growth").hover(function () { ...
    */

    function ic() {
        $("div#text2").slideUp(200)
        $("p").removeClass("emphasis");
        $("p.competency").eq(k - 1).slideDown(300).siblings().hide()
        return false
    }

    function times() {
        $("p.growth").removeClass("emphasis");
        $(this).addClass("emphasis");
        $("div#text2").slideDown(200);
        $(".competency").hide();
        k = $(this).index() + 1;

        $(".1").fadeTo(1000, 1);
        if (k == 2) $(".2").fadeTo(1000, 0.7);
        if (k == 3) $(".3").fadeTo(1000, 0.6);

        $("div#container1").click(ic);
        return false
    }

    $(".growth").on('click', times)

    $("[id^=ul]").hide();
    $("p[id^=ptext]").hide();
    $("p[id^=act]").hide();

    $("#p1, #p2, #p3").click(function () {
        var nr = this.id.split('p')[1];
        $("p[id^=ptext]").hide(400);
        $("#ptext" + nr).delay(400).slideToggle(300);
        $("[id^=ul]").hide(400);
        $("#ul" + nr).delay(400).slideToggle(300);

    });

    $("li[id^=act]").mouseover(function () {
        var nr = this.id.split('act')[1];
        $("p[id^=act]").hide(0);
        $("p#act" + nr).delay(100).slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```

Added CSS:

```
.growth:hover {
    color:#666;
    font-size: 30px;
    left: -40px;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6vK7k/)